Does sunscreen protect against radiation from an atomic bomb detonation?
In the moments leading up to the Trinity detonation, Edward Teller is depicted applying
sunscreen to his face:

Does sunscreen protect against radiation from an atomic bomb detonation?

@everyone This question in its original version seems to be on-topic. So, please avoid making substantial changes to the post.

I’m voting to close this question because the question in its current revision appears to be off-topic. This isn't a movies and TV question, but rather a science question. Another Stack Exchange site would probably be a better fit for this question. The [[tag:realism]] tag is for evaluating the realism of media depictions, not for explaining real-world science.

@AJ - I think you're wrong. I think this is going to get closed by the community and then edited back to revision 2.

@Valorum I think changing from "why sunscreen" to "what thing" is a substantial change. So, it is not a good edit. And doing so just to make it fit the answer you have is also not a good practice.

@Valorum It's up to the community whether they want to keep it open or close. I'd not interfere with this. However, we do entertain questions about science in movies/TV shows and its real-world applications, AFAIK.

@AJ - I didn't do it to fit my answer, I did it because the original question was palpably off-topic. I answered it after the edit had been made and you've now made it off-topic (again). You'll note that I also made efforts to respect their original question by addressing the efficacy of sun cream

@AJ - Now it's closed, perhaps we might consider returning it to a version that's actually on-topic

@MaxPower Just wanted to check—is revision 2 in line with what you were aiming for with your question? Right now, the community closed your question because revision 1 came across as a real-life science question rather than something related to movies and TV. If revision 2 reflects your intent, rolling back to it could help us reopen the question.

From the script

Teller, in dark glasses, is APPLYING SUNSCREEN at night

As for the original question (now edited out)

Does sunscreen protect against radiation from an atomic bomb detonation?

Actual dangerous* radiation?
Of course not.
However, it does protect against UV (ultraviolet) "radiation" which would accompany the light emitted by the detonation.
*Not to suggest that UV is not harmful but it's not immediately dangerous. As pointed out in the comments...

Ultraviolet light might not kill immediately or within days, or weeks, or months, or even years, but does cause skin cancer which will eventually kill if not treated.

Just moments before Teller and Feynman were discussing protection from UV

Feynman TAPS the windshield
FEYNMAN: The glass stops the UV.


Why did you write that sunscreen doesn't protect against actual dangerous radiation from an atomic blast and then write that it protects against ultraviolet light.  You write like you think that ultraviolet light isn't dangerous.  Ultraviolet light might not kill immediately or within days, or weeks, or months, or even years, but does cause skin cancer which will eventually kill if not treated.  I have had six cases of skin cancer removed from my skin so I don't think that ultraviolet light is not dangerous.

@M.A.Golding  Apologies if that is the way it came across. I'm aware of the issues UV can cause, answer updated and included your point.

Edward Teller was, in his own words, applying (zinc oxide?) sunscreen ointment to his face.

I wouldn’t turn away. I wanted to look the beast in the eye. But
having made all those calculations, I thought the blast might be
rather bigger than expected. So I put on some suntan lotion. I put on
a pair of dark glasses. I pulled on a pair of heavy gloves. With both
hands I pressed the welder’s glass against my face, making sure no
stray light could penetrate around it. I then looked straight at the
aim point.
Energy from Heaven and Earth by Edward Teller

He also offered it to other scientists, who eagerly accepted, according to William L. Laurence, the Manhattan Project's official historian.

Someone produced sunburn lotion and passed it around. It was an eerie
sight to see a number of our highest-ranking scientists seriously
rubbing sunburn lotion on their faces and hands in the pitch blackness
of the night, twenty miles away from the expected flash. These were
the men who, more than anybody else, knew the potentialities of atomic
energy on the loose. It gave one an inkling of their confidence in
their handiwork.
Dawn Over Zero by William L. Lawrence


As to the efficacy of 'sun cream versus a nuclear bomb', that was discussed by nuclear physicist Gregg Spriggs in a video for Insider. Given that the yield was unknown, taking precautions was sensible, but definitely proved to be overkill given the small yield of the test bomb and the distance of the bunker.




"They were all laying down thinking that the shock wave might get to them and if they were laying down that it wouldn't be a direct hit. You don't want to have a big surface area if the shock wave is coming over. You want to be kind of laying flat. There have been situations where we've had tests where the yield was a little bit higher than what people thought or the wind blew the bomb a little bit closer to the observers, that people have actually gotten a little bit of a sunburn. I don't think the sunscreen would've helped very much. It's basically a heat flux that hits you. I guess it would've helped a little bit, but not much."
Transcript from Oppenheimer: Nuclear Expert Reveals True Effectiveness Of Sunscreen In Trinity Test Scene

